# Automatically stretch or shrink `<textField>` depending on text length?

Tags: jasper-reports

I have two `<textField>` one by one. Is possible to automatically stretch or shrink them depending on text length? The only attribute which hit my eyes, was the `isStretchWithOverflow` but cause that one text is covering another - that is not what I meant. Anybody helps? Is it even possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you are talking about stretch vertically.

In that case `isStretchWithOverflow` is exactly what you need.

The second `<textfield>` covered by first one is because the position setting. You probably has it setting to `Fix`, so it dose not move while first one stretched. Change the position setting of second `<textfield>` to `Float` should works.

Comment: What with more than two `<textField>` - Do i need to set the position on all but the first to `Float` ?

Comment: How about stretch width dynamically?

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible using pure HTML/CSS.  However, you could do it by using Javascript.  One way would be to bind a keypress event handler to your input which updates its width.

If you use JQuery, something like:

```
 $(yourInput).keypress(function(){
     $(this).css("width", $(this).val().length * 5);
 });
```

should do the trick (although you'll probably want to adjust the calculation; I have no idea if 5px per character is too much or too little).

Comment: Question relates to [Jasper Reports](http://jasperforge.org/projects/jasperreports), not HTML.

Comment: There was no mention of Jasper at all except in the tags; if OP wanted a Jasper-specific answer they really should have said so in the question.